# Bulk insert field mapping incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to do a bulk insert.

Here is my sql script

```
GO
Use test
DROP TABLE PDTEST
create table pdtest
(
 CustID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
 work_phone_extension varchar(5),
 residential_postal_or_zip_code varchar(30),
 residential_street_address_line_1 varchar(30),
 residence_phone varchar(17),
 work_phone varchar(17),
 name_part varchar(30),
 mailing_city varchar(20),
 mailing_postal_or_zip_code varchar(30),
 mailing_street_address_line_2 varchar(30),
 mailing_street_address_line_1 varchar(30),
 cell_phone varchar(17),
 residential_city varchar(20),
 residential_country_and_province_or_state varchar(10),
 mailing_country_and_province_or_state varchar(10)
)
BULK INSERT pdtest
FROM 'C:\Python27\Scripts\pd.csv'
WITH
(
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
 KEEPNULLS,
 FIRSTROW = 2
)
GO
```

Here is my textfile row

```
,91234,,,,WOLFIE HOWLETT,416-,Toronto,,,,,Toronto,CA_ON,CA_ON
```

All my columns are messed up.The name part should have Wolfie Howlett. It has 416- and then the work phone extension should be null but it has got value 91234 and residential_postal_or_zip_code is null which is wrong.

The field mapping is wrong here.What should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is you have a comma as your first character, so SQL is treating that empty space before it as a column value and inserting that into CustID, so everything is right-shifted by one. So either create a dummy column in your test table before CustID, or remove the first comma in your rows.

Comment: I cannot make changes to text file

Answer (score 0):

sorry to say but you have to edit your text file. It is creating a syntax error, so has to be modified. I can suggest you way that you can remove and add new text file, with same name and at same location.

Seeing your syntax, it seems you had given 'auto increment' to your first column. So, you need not have to provide value for CustID, and no need of keeping that starting comma in csv file.

Sql will take CustId value by its own. Provide below syntax for csv file

```
91234,,,,WOLFIE HOWLETT,416-,Toronto,,,,,Toronto,CA_ON,CA_ON
```

Hope it will help !